# React JS: Pass A value from route to component

Tags: reactjs

I have these routes

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/reports" exact component={ReportPage} />
    <Route path="/reports/browse" exact component={ActiveReportsPage} />
    <Route path="/signin" exact component={SigninPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>;
```

And I want to use this - /reports/browse/[ VALUE ] for example - (localhost:8000/reports/browse/1)

I need to access the VALUE from `ActiveReportsPage` to call an API. I need to pass in the Value which I get from the URL to Axios API call, how can I make it?

This is my `ActiveReportsPage`, as you can see

> `this.props.getReports(3);` Calls the API and instead of 3 I should pass the VALUE

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getReports } from '../actions/reports';

export class ActiveReportsPage extends Component {

    static PropTypes = {
        reports: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getReports(3); {/* I need to pass in the argument from /reports/browse/< 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 > */}
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h2>hello :P</h2>
        )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    reports: state.reports.reports
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getReports })(ActiveReportsPage);
```

Comment: How your route will get item number can you show that function or map function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `params` through the Router, which is accessible through the `match` prop:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/reports/:parameter" exact component={ReportPage} />
    <Route path="/reports/browse" exact component={ActiveReportsPage} />
    <Route path="/signin" exact component={SigninPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>;
```

and will then be accessible in the ReportsPage component as: `this.props.match.params.parameter`

Comment: Works like a miracle:)_

Answer (score 1):

also you can `useParams`

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/reports/:parameter" exact component={ReportPage} />
    <Route path="/reports/browse" exact component={ActiveReportsPage} />
    <Route path="/signin" exact component={SigninPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

and in component `ReportPage` use `useParams`
`let { parameter } = useParams()`.